# How to load a list of users and render them in parallel?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parallel-processing

In an angularjs application, I have a list of user ids, and want to retrieve them in parallel, then display them on the page, but I don't know how to do it.

My code for now is looking like:

```
<ul ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <li ng-repeat="user in users">User id: {{user.id}}, name: {{user.name}}</li>
</ul>

app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.userIds = [1,2,3,4, ... to 100];
    $scope.users = [];
    $scope.userIds.each(function(id) {
       $http.get("/users/"+id)
         .success(function(data) {
            // data is a json, like:
            // {
            //    id: ???,
            //    name: ???
            // }
            // 
            $scope.users.append(data);
         });
    })

})
```

You can see the users are retrieved one by one, and the order maybe disturbed. If there any better way to it in Angular?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using an array of promises:

```
    var promises = [];

    $scope.userIds = [111,222,333,444, ... to 100];
    $scope.users = [];

    for(var i = 0 ; i < $scope.userIds.length ; i++){

        var deffered  = $q.defer();
        var userId = $scope.userIds[i]; 

        $http.get("/users/"+userId).
        success(function(data){
            $scope.users.append(data);
            deffered.resolve(data);
        }).
        error(function(error){
            deffered.reject();
        });

        promises.push(deffered.promise);
    }

    return $q.all(promises).then(function(){
        //here will be code, that should run when all users loaded
    });
```

Comment: With the promises, the user information can only be show when all the users have been retrieved?

Comment: Is is possible to show any user if its data has been retrieved

Comment: Actually it will(should be) shown when each user comes. I assume that in html you using `ng-repeat` to display users, so in each `success` call array of users will be updated => view will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about angularjs, but i think you can use [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async).For example:

```
$scope.userIds = [111,222,333,444];
var tasks = {};
$scope.userIds.each(function(id) {
    tasks[id.toString()] = function(callback) {
        $http.get("/users/"+id).success(function(data) {

            //you can update Html at here

            callback(null, data);
        });
    };
});

async.parallel(tasks, function(err, users) {
    //users: { '111': { id: ???, name: ??? }, '222': { id: ???, name: ??? },...} 
});
```